# Local cache of mercurial repository: how to get "hg incoming" to pull, which hook?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I use a local repository cache so my clones are faster.
When I clone I clone from the local cache, which auto-updates before the clone actually starts. When I push, I push to the local cache which first updates and then (when the push is successfull) pushes the changesets onwards to the canonical repository.

However: I want "hg incoming" to work as follows:

1. I make a clone of the local cache repository
2. ..hack hack hack in the clone of the local cache..(hey are there any incoming changes? I wonder)
3. $ hg in
4. The local cache repository gets asked "are there any new changesets?"
5. The local cache then first does hg pull
6. Then it answers the question

Is this possible? Is there a hook I can use in the local cache repository that fires when it gets a "hg incoming" command?

The .hgrc in my local cache looks like:

```
[hooks]
# We want to make sure this repository has the latest changesets just before
# we do a clone of it.
preoutgoing.update_local_cache1 = echo "======================"
preoutgoing.update_local_cache2 = echo "hg pull from canonical"
preoutgoing.update_local_cache3 = echo "======================"
preoutgoing.update_local_cache4 = hg pull

# Before we push commits to the local cache make sure it's up to date.
prechangegroup.update_local_cache1 = echo "======================"
prechangegroup.update_local_cache2 = echo "hg pull from canonical"
prechangegroup.update_local_cache3 = echo "======================"
prechangegroup.update_local_cache4 = hg pull

# Just after a bunch of changesets have been succesfully pushed to this local
# cache repository, push it further to the canonical repository.
changegroup.push_to_canonical1 = echo "===================="
changegroup.push_to_canonical2 = echo "hg push to canonical"
changegroup.push_to_canonical3 = echo "===================="
changegroup.push_to_canonical4 = hg push
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no hook you can use in the local cache to catch when one of your working clones is checking for incoming available stuff.  Your best best is probably to get the working clones to do the pull in the local cache.  Something like in your user-wide `~/.hgrc` file should do it

```
[hooks]
pre-incoming = $HG --repository /path/to/local/cache pull
```

THen whenever you do `hg incoming` in any repository you'll do a pull in the local cache first.  That, of course, won't work well when you're running `hg incoming` in the actual local cache, turning it into a pull instead, but no tragedy.

Comment: I don't think there's a pre-incoming hook.

Comment: There's a `pre-*` (and `post-*`) for every built in hook.  They're not-gating (you can't cancel that action) and there's not a lot of in context, but they exist to just do things before and after.  This means there are *separate* pre-commit and precommit hooks that behave differently!  They're client-side hooks, so you can't put them on your cache-clone and expect them to work, but you can install them globally on your client.  http://selenic.com/hg/file/c915d066bcac/mercurial/help/config.txt#l624